# how to use custom post types collectively integrated with each other

Tags: custom-post-types, bbpress, customization

i will star with some back ground and my goal before i gt to the point

i am trying to make a anime viewing website using wordpress like 
www.watchanimeon.com and 
www.animedreaming.tv
i tried a couple of techniques like tiring to use custom fields to store data but of no avail as they all got way too complected for a little guy like me .

*i use categories for the anime series
and post for the episodes them selves
but for the part where i wanted my sits users or members to be able to add mirror videos i got stuck i came up with the half solution of my problem with wordpress oembbed feature or though to use [autoembed](http://autoembed.com/) in my template but the area where i wanted the ablity of mirror videos i tried to use tdo mini forms but did not succeeded because of knowing no means of saving this data in the post it self*

then i came assross these wordpress custom post types and after the release of bbpress 2 it accord to me that if i could separate post types for series, episodes and mirrors (or videos) like in bbpress forums, topics and posts and have a series act like category then i will also be able to tag anime generas and the series will list the episodes associated with and every episode list the videos associated with it most of my work will be done but i cant find any way to do this as i told earlier that i am a little guy in the field don't know much about programming and learns by google

so please help me plz plz

and in any case any one of you still dont understand what i am trying to accomplish check this (http://www.watchanimeon.com/sket-dance-episode-30/) link thats what i want to be able to do and also look at the bbpress2 to see what i am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand right you want to create relations between custom post types, you can achieve this with this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/

after installing go to your functions.php and setup relations

```
<?php
function my_connection_types() {
    // Make sure the Posts 2 Posts plugin is active.
    if ( !function_exists( 'p2p_register_connection_type' ) )
        return;

    p2p_register_connection_type( array(
        'id' => 'series_to_episodes',
        'from' => 'series_custom_type',
        'to' => 'episodes_custom_type'
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_connection_types', 100 );
?>
```

you can create how many relations you want

Comment: ok let me try doing that